# How to prevent WordPress Media Library from removing image?

Tags: wordpress, delete-file, media-library, wordpress-media

I have a custom post type that must have its feature image. Its feature image also appears in the Media Library where user can delete the image/attachment file permanently. But I want to prevent user from deleting the feature image of my custom post type. So I use the following hook to intercept the ajax request, validate if user is deleting the image of my custom post type and stop the process by using `wp_die()`.

```
add_filter('pre_delete_attachment', 'check_my_custom_post_type', 0, 2);
function check_my_custom_post_type($delete, $post) {
    if (Yes it is image of my custom type) {
        wp_die('My message', 'My title', ['response' => 400]);
    }
}
```

It works fine on the server side. The image of my custom post type cannot be deleted. But Media Library, on the client side, still removes the image from its views even the image on the server side has not been deleted and an exception 400 has been thrown.

How to prevent Media Library from removing images from its views on the client side if image has not been deleted on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

In [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_delete_attachment/) second parameter is `bool|null`. Try to `return false` instead of `wp_die`

Comment: I have tried with `return false`, but the Media Library stills removed the image from its views. It's weird that Media Library assumes that image will always be deleted successfully on the server side. Looking in the `media-views.js` file, I think this method `this.model.destroy();` removes the image from the Media Library views when AJAX request is complete. I cannot see what is in that `this.model.destroy()`  function.

Comment: @OConnor Also you can try to disable ajax call with `wp_ajax_query-attachments` `wp_ajax_nopriv_query-attachments` actions and call `exit` in function.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the delete link totally using the [`wp_prepare_attachment_for_js`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_prepare_attachment_for_js/) hook.

```php
function remove_media_delete_link_in_grid_view( $response ) {
    $response['nonces']['delete'] = false;

    return $response;
}
add_filter( 'wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', 'remove_media_delete_link_in_grid_view' );
```

This works also with the "Bulk Delete" action. If the attachment has this `nonce` value `false`, it will not be deleted with the other bulk selected attachments .

But this works only with the **Grid** View that uses the `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` hook. The **List** view doesn't use any Javascript. So, to prevent deleting media files in the List view, you have to:

- Remove the individual delete link of each media item in the list using the [`media_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_row_actions/) hook.
- And remove the delete option from the bulk actions menu using the [`bulk_actions-{$screen}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/bulk_actions-this-screen-id/) hook.

```php
function remove_media_delete_link_in_list_view( $actions ) {
    unset( $actions['delete'] );

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'media_row_actions',   'remove_media_delete_link_in_list_view' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-upload', 'remove_media_delete_link_in_list_view' );
```